# React state vs props for complex structure

Tags: api, reactjs

I did example where my react fetches data from API.

I have the following mockup

- List of objects
  -- Object
  --- Select field

this is my OrdersList.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Order from './Order';

class OrdersList extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { data: [] }
  }
  componentDidMount() {

    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/v1/orders',
      success: data => this.setState({ data: data }),
      error: error => console.log(error)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col s12">
          <table className="floatThead bordered highlight">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>status</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <Order data = { this.state.data } />
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default OrdersList;
```

here is my Order.jsx (it has Item to list and ItemStatus)

```
import React from 'react'

class OrderStatus extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { data: [] }
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    let data = {
      order: {
        status: event.target.value
      }
    }
    console.log(event)
    $.ajax({
      method: 'PUT',
      url: `/api/v1/orders/${event.target.id}`,
      data: data,
      success: data => (console.log(data), this.setState({ data: data })),
      error: error => console.log(error)
    })

  }
  render() {

    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="input-field">
          <p>status: {this.props.data.status}</p>
          <select value={ this.props.data.status } id={ this.props.data.id } onChange={ this.handleChange } className="browser-default" >
            <option value='neworder'>new</option>
            <option value='pendingorder'>pending</option>
            <option value='sentorder'>sent</option>
            <option value='completedorder'>done</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Order extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { data: [] }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <tbody>
        {
          this.props.data.map(
            order =>
            <tr key={order.id}>
              <td>
                # {order.id}
              </td>
              <td>
                <OrderStatus data={ order } />
              </td>
            </tr>
          )
        }
      </tbody>
    )
  }
}

export default Order;
```

What I am not able to understand is how to update my item status on ajax callback (there is update in backend, it works just fine, but how to update my status state on child item which is being listed by map function).. Appreciate for your input!

Comment: My ajax callback says -- "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine, you are just missing a bind statement.

Add the following to your constructor and it should work:

```
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
```

For reference check this [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes).

Comment: Thanks! I can see something changed.. however why does my <p>status: {this.props.data.status}</p> never update it-self (unless I reload the page F5) ? I don't see errors in console now..

Comment: You are updating the child components state, so it gets rerendered. The parent component won't be updated as you don't modify the state. To modify the parent state from the child you have to pass a function to the child. The function should update the parent state and has to be called from the child. Something like: `this.props.updateParent();`

Comment: You did my day Sir Graubner! Appreciate your input. I just want to clarify few things I've done and if possible correct me if this is not best practise. I added function to parent Item that does pretty the same like my componentDidMount (calls ajax and sets state for my index page data). In my child onChange callback I put this.props.updateParent() -- which is my function that calls my parent .. I am on ES6, so I did not forget to bind this new function in my constructor (i.e.     this.updateParent = this.updateParent.bind(this))

Comment: and passed this from parent to child when called child component (i.e.             <Order data = { this.state.data } updateParent = { this.updateParent }  />

Comment: It this best practise? I've checked your reply as answer.

Comment: You are welcome. Thats the way to do it. You might consider to refactor your code a bit to handle the change with just one function. Currently you have to call a function in child and in parent. Maybe you can handle the change in the parent component and only pass the data to the child. That's a little bit cleaner. Also [Container Components](https://css-tricks.com/learning-react-container-components/) might be interesting for you. Those seperate data management and presentational logic.